# moving file from one location to another without knowing file name

Tags: c#, file

One of my executable process produces two files. I want to move one file that is produced to shared drive. I am writing an automatic process to move the file from one location to shared drive. The only issue is file name changes every time the executable is run so I don't have the exact filename with me. I only have the extension, .xls. I have only one .xls file in my directory.

I tried doing this

```
File.Copy(@"*.xls", @"\\serv44\Application\testing\name\test2\*.xls", true);
```

It threw an error saying Invalid name. After moving the file to shared drive. I want to delete the .xls file.

```
File.Delete("*.xls");
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Query for the files with Directory.GetFiles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should get file name and then do whatever you want with that file. I.e. if you have only one xls file in the source directory:

```
var targetDirectory = @"\\serv44\Application\testing\name\test2\";
var sourceFile = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.xls").FirstOrDefault();
if (sourceFile != null)
{
    var sourceFileName = Path.GetFileName(sourceFile);
    var targetFileName = Path.Combine(targetDirectory, sourceFileName);
    File.Copy(sourceFileName, targetFileName);
    File.Delete(sourceFileName);
}
```

Note: instead of copy and delete you can use single `Move` operation.

If you want to move several files from your source directory, then instead of taking first one process all found files in a loop:

```
 foreach(var sourceFile in Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.xls"))
 {
     var sourceFileName = Path.GetFileName(sourceFile);
     var targetFileName = Path.Combine(targetDirectory, sourceFileName);
     File.Move(sourceFileName, targetFileName);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you that file name:

```
var fileName = Directory.GetFiles(yourDirectory, "*.xls").ToList().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: The `GetFiles` method returns an array. Then you convert it into a list - why? And in the end take only the first value. Everything else goes in the trash. Imagine that folder contains million files.

Comment: As Anjali stated, there is only one xls file in directory so why to imagine milion files? I converted only one item array to list to be able to use FirstOrDefault() method, which I think is useful here.

Comment: I could directly return the zero position item but I wanted to put a empty array check